# Wikipedia search discord bot command

Tags: python, bots, wikipedia, discord

this is my first time coding a bot and I need help with my Wikipedia bot on Discord. It is written with wikipedia api.

```
wikipedia = wikipedia.summary('', sentences=1, chars=100, 
auto_suggest=True, redirect=True)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!define'):
       await client.send_message(message.channel, wikipedia)
```

How do I get the bot to recognise the search in the first line? I want the command to search the word placed after !define.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see this is code has multiple problems. Firstly, your `wikipedia` variable needs to be a function, it seems as though you may not of grasped some of the basics of python, and if that is the case I recommend you read about functions [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) or [here](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions). A function can take one or several arguments and return a value. In your case you would want to pass an argument with the term you want to define, and the returned value would be the definition. The snytax for this would be something like:

```
def wiki_summary(arg):

    definition = wikipedia.summary(arg, sentences=1, chars=100, 
    auto_suggest=True, redirect=True)
    return definition
```

In your client.send_message function you then want to call your newly created function, you can do this with `client.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(arg)`, where arg is replaced with the term you want wikipedia to define.
In your case this would be all the words in the message after "!define". The simplest way to do this is to use `.split()` ([Docs](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split)), this seperates a string into substrings, the default seperator is space, and creates a list containing all the substrings. To get all the words after the first word ("!define") you can use [list indices](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) ([start:end]), to select everything but the first object in a list you use list[1:], this starts the selection at list[1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) and ends it at the end of the list. In code this looks something like this:

```
words = message.content.split()
important_words = words[1:]
```

You then want to pass these important words as the arg in your `wikipedia` function, like so:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!define'):
       words = message.content.split()
       important_words = words[1:]
       await client.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(important_words)
```

An improvement, as suggested by Aaron, would be to have "!define" be case insensitive, meaning that it doesn't matter wether the user types "!Define" or "!DeFInE", both will be accepted by the bot. To do this we can use `.lower()` (Or any other unified capitalization function). This makes all characters in a string lowercase. To use this we would check if the first word of the users message in lowercase is the same as "!define" (in lowercase). Like so:

```
if message.content.split()[0].lower() == "!define"
```

A few things are happening at once here, first we `.split()` the message to get a list of the words, then access the first word with a list indice of 0, then make it lowercase, and finally we compare it to your "!define" keyword.

Since this checks whether or not the first word in a message is "!define" we can replace our `.startswith()` function with this. As such:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
words = message.content.split()
    if words[0].lower() == "!define":
       important_words = words[1:]
       await client.send_message(message.channel, wiki_summary(important_words))
```

Comment: I would rename the `wikipedia` function to something else for clarity. `wiki_summary(search_term)` is far less likely to be confused with `wikipedia`, the module. Otherwise you hit on all the points in the answer I was typing. Another recommendation is to call `if message.content.lower().startswith('!define')` to ensure that users don't need to worry too much about capitalization when invoking the command (both for humour and for catching typing errors that are easy for the bot to correct). Might as well declare `words` at the top, followed by `if words[0].lower() == 'define!'`

Comment: You're right, I'll edit my answer accordingly, thanks.
Sorry for stealing your answer.

Comment: Haha, no worries. We're all here to help eachother out and rep isn't that important in comparison to answers which will stand the test of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should also change "@client.event" to "@client.listen()" so your other bot commands will work.